# What is \reset@font?

Tags: fonts, mathrm

I've seen `\reset@font` (often immediately before `\mathrm` or `\footnotesize`) in macros and I was wondering what it does.

Comment: it is just an old name for `\normalfont` as shown in the answer, but it's a text font command, you should not see it in front of `\mathrm` in any cases I can think of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, `\reset@font` reverts to the normal/default font.

The easiest way to see what it does is to `\show` it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\large Large

\makeatletter
\reset@font
\show\reset@font
\makeatother

Normal

\end{document}
```

The above yields

```
> \reset@font=macro:
->\protect \normalfont
```

in the `.log`.

You can also take a gander at the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) where you'll find

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\normalfont
                 {\usefont\encodingdefault
                          \familydefault
                          \seriesdefault
                          \shapedefault
                  \relax}
\let\reset@font\normalfont
```

Comment: Clearly I was a minute too late. :)